# Semantic Versioning

Tags: apify

I want to use Semantic Versioning of an act, but I am not familiar with it and want to learn the professional way. So I have the following problems:

1. How can I sent version for example to 1.0, if the Fork-Link is deactivated (see Screenshot).
2. How is the recomenden workflow for versioning?
3. Who does Apify-Versioning correspond with the version number in package.json?
4. What does the link 'Delete' actually delete, the whole act, the version or the version-number?

Regards Wulfgäääng

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't support the Semantic versioning of actors right now.

You can use the current versioning system as you wish but I have summarized the [best practices from our point](https://help.apify.com/en/articles/3202824-versioning-of-public-actors).

1. There is a limit of 10 versions per actor so you may want to delete some unused ones. If this will be issue for more users, we may increase the limit.
2. Explained in the article.
3. It doesn't at all.
4. It deletes the version - the number and the source code for this particular version. But the builds with this version stay so you can still use them.